# Exception handling for non integers in a class definition

Tags: python, exception

I created a class called "Fraction" and in it's constructor, I want to be able to test and see if either the numerator or denominator are not integers. I've written an if else statement to raise an error or create an object, but no matter whether either is an integer or not I get an error. Also, I get a completely different error if I do enter a string, for example, so this doesn't seem to be working at all. Is this the proper implementation?

```
class Fraction:
num = 0
den = 0

def __init__(self, top, bottom):
    if top != int or bottom != int:
        raise RuntimeError("Bad value for top or bottom")
    else:
        gcd, remainder = 0, 0
        n, m = top, bottom
        while (n != 0):
            remainder = m % n
            m = n
            n = remainder
        gcd = m
        self.num = top // gcd
        self.den = bottom // gcd

def show(self):
    print(self.num, "/", self.den)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.num) + "/" + str(self.den)

def getNum(self):
    print(self.num)

def getDen(self):
    print(self.den)

def __add__(self, otherFraction):
    newNum = self.num*otherFraction.den + self.den * otherFraction.num
    newDen = self.den * otherFraction.den

    return Fraction(newNum, newDen)

def __sub__(self, otherFraction):
    newNum = self.num * otherFraction.den - self.den * otherFraction.num
    newDen = self.den * otherFraction.den

    return Fraction(newNum, newDen)

def __mul__(self, otherFraction):
    newNum = self.num * otherFraction.num
    newDen = self.den * otherFraction.den

    return Fraction(newNum, newDen)

def __truediv__(self, otherFraction):
    newNum = self.num * otherFraction.den
    newDen = self.den * otherFraction.num

    return Fraction(newNum, newDen)
def __gt__(self, other):
    return ((self.num * other.den) > (self.den * other.num))

def __ge__(self, other):
    return ((self.num * other.den) >= (self.den * other.num))

def __lt__(self, other):
    return ((self.num * other.den) < (self.den * other.num))

def __le__(self, other):
    return ((self.num * other.den) <= (self.den * other.num))

def _ne__(self, other):
    return ((self.num * other.den) != (self.den * other.num))

frac = Fraction(5, 16)
frac2 = Fraction(3, 16)

print(frac.show())
print(frac.getNum())
print(frac.getDen())

print(frac + frac2)
print(frac - frac2)
print(frac * frac2)
print(frac / frac2)
print(frac > frac2)
print(frac >= frac2)
print(frac < frac2)
print(frac <= frac2)
print(frac != frac2)
```

Comment: I think you should remove `num = 0` and  `den = 0` after the class statement.  You should also check for `bottom==0` and raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `isinstance` instead of equality.

```
if not(isinstance(top,int) and isinstance(bottom, int)):
```